# Handling objects of different class types as values in a map in java

Tags: java, object, dictionary

I'd like to create a map or hash-map (or something similar) that looks something like this:

```
Map < string, ? > items = new Map < string, ?>();
items.put("string" , classObject);
items.put("string2" , classObjectOfDifferentType);
items.put("string3" , classObjectOfAnotherType);
```

The idea is to create something of a static look up table that will contain objects of unique class types as values. I'll pass in a string and return the object I want.

I tried creating a map like this:

```
private final String STRINGVALUE = "STRINGVALUE";
private Map<String, Object> handlers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
private static StringHandler STRING_HANDLER;

//creation of StringHandler using the Spring framework here

handlers.put(STRINGVALUE, STRING_HANDLER);
```

I'm getting a strange, unhelpful error, though, on the parentheses of the 'put' call.

So what's the right way to do this?

edit:

errors are:
"syntax error on )"
"syntax error on ("

Comment: change it to `String` from `string`, and share error

Comment: And, perchance, would you care to share this error?

Comment: Your code seems to compile. What is the error message you're getting? It is probably more helpful than you think.

Comment: is there a method where handler.put is called? Th eerror seems to be outside your posted code.

Comment: I'm a derp, answer below is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `handlers.put` call needs to be inside a method or a constructor or an initializer block. You can't have statements just floating around in the class.